# excel formula to subtract number of days from a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

is there a way in Excel to have a formula that does something like this:

= 12/20/2010 - 180

which would take a certain date (12/20/2010 in this case) and subtract 180 days . .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the original date is in cell A1:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1)-180)
```

Comment: Or all in one cell,

=DATE(2010,12,20)-180

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the original date is in cell A1:

```
=A1-180
```

Works in at least Excel 2003 and 2010.

Answer (score 4):

You can paste it like this:

```
= "2010-12-20" - 180
```

And don't forget to format the cell as a Date [CTRL]+[F1] / Number Tab

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me (Excel 14.0 - aka MS Office Pro Plus 2010):

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1), DAY(A1) - 16)
```

This takes the date (format mm/dd/yyyy) in cell A1 and subtracts 16 days with output in format of mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Say the **1st date** is in `A1 cell` & the **2nd date** is in `B1 cell`

Make sure that the *cell type* of both `A1` & `B1` is `DATE`.
Then simply put the following formula in C1:

```
=A1-B1
```

The result of this formula may look funny to you.
Then Change the Cell type of `C1` to `GENERAL`.

It will give you the difference in Days.

You can also use this formula to get the remaining days of year or change the formula as you need:

```
=365-(A1-B1)
```