# Changing one date based on another in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a cell A7 that changes to the date 2 days prior to date input in another cell A5.

Comment: have you even once tried to Google your "problem" ?

Comment: Please show us what you tried, also, Googling gives you many answers: `excel subtract days from date`

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @PeterB The formula I have right now is: =DateAdd("d", -2, A5) and it is giving me #NAME? Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [excel formula to subtract number of days from a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609753/excel-formula-to-subtract-number-of-days-from-a-date)

Answer (score 1):

The DateFormula does what you Need:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A5),MONTH(A5),DAY(A5)-2)
```

-- leaving this here because still true for VBA --

The DateAdd function is only available in VBA, not as a cellfunction

Put this in A7:

```
=DateAdd("d", -2, A5)
```

[first Google result](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php)

Comment: The formula I have right now is: =DateAdd("d", -2, A5) and it is giving me #NAME? Do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: Adding days should actually work without a formula, so just: `=A5-2` or try: `=DATE(YEAR(A5),MONTH(A5),DAY(A5)-2)`

Comment: I updated my answer, DateAdd is not a Cellfunction, sorry for that

Comment: =A5-2 worked. I guess I was trying to over complicate it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: mind marking as answer? that formula will also work :D